# How to create blob: url for local file with FF ext

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm writing a FF ext which has the filepath to an existing file, and I simply want to create a [`blob:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Blob) url for the file, without creating an `<input type="file"` field which the user has to interact with. Creating a hidden `<input type="file"` element which the user does not need to interact with would be fine.

I have chrome privileges since this is for a FF ext, so **is there a way to do this?**

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/Using_files_from_web_applications#Using_blob_URLs) whart you are looking for?

Comment: no I want to figure out how to create the file obj, that link assumes I have one.